# Parsing XML return NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have following XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<menu>
  <item>
    <id>0</id>
    <name>Pizzerie u soudu</name>
    <street>Havlíčkova 3</street>
    <city>779 00 Olomouc</city>
    <mobile>777035862</mobile>
    <telephone>585223042</telephone>
    <openinghours>10-22</openinghours>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Pepinova pizza</name>
    <street>©meralova 10</street>
    <city>779 00 Olomouc</city>
    <mobile>776102022</mobile>
    <telephone>-</telephone>
    <openinghours>8-22</openinghours>
  </item>
</menu>
```

and I would like to parse it by following code:

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element)nl.item(i);
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_STREET, parser.getValue(e, KEY_STREET));
            map.put(KEY_CITY, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CITY));
            map.put(KEY_MOBILE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MOBILE));
            map.put(KEY_TELEPHONE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TELEPHONE));
            map.put(KEY_OPENINGHOURS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_OPENINGHOURS));
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
```

but I have problem on line

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

It returns `java.lang.NullPointerException`
What's wrong?

Comment: How do you initialize doc? could you please enclose that code as well. Like Samir said - doc is null.

Comment: Please, provide the code where you initialize the "doc" variable.

Comment: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
     XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
     String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
     Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-xml-parsing-using-dom-parser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you `XMLParser` code is your proprietary and `getDomElement` method is returning NULL for some reason like file is not found in path or some other errors. Even if the standard API's please check whether there are any condition that returns doc value as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class parsing {
public  void parse() {

try {

File file = new File("F:\\JavaProjects\\JavaApplication12\\src\\javaapplication12\\urdoc.xml");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

String id,name,street,city,mo,tel,oh;
for (int s = 0; s < nodes.getLength(); s++) {

Node fstNode = nodes.item(s);

System.out.println("Node.ELEMENT_NODE:"+Node.ELEMENT_NODE);
if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
     Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
NodeList idp= element.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getChildNodes();
id = ((Node) idp.item(0)).getNodeValue();

NodeList np= element.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getChildNodes();
name = ((Node) np.item(0)).getNodeValue();

NodeList sp= element.getElementsByTagName("street").item(0).getChildNodes();
street = ((Node) sp.item(0)).getNodeValue();


NodeList cp = element.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getChildNodes();
city = ((Node) cp.item(0)).getNodeValue();

NodeList mp = element.getElementsByTagName("mobile").item(0).getChildNodes();
mo= ((Node) mp.item(0)).getNodeValue();    

NodeList tp = element.getElementsByTagName("telephone").item(0).getChildNodes();
tel= ((Node) tp.item(0)).getNodeValue();   

NodeList op= element.getElementsByTagName("openinghours").item(0).getChildNodes();
oh= ((Node) op.item(0)).getNodeValue();   





   System.out.println("After parsing..");
   System.out.println("id "+id);
   System.out.println("name "+name);
   System.out.println("city "+city);
   System.out.println("street "+street);
   System.out.println("telephone "+tel);
   System.out.println(" mobile"+tel);
   System.out.println(" oh"+oh);


    }

}
}
 catch (Exception e)
  { 
  System.out.print("Exception: "+e);

}
}
}
```

Comment: He isn't asking how to parse, but he had error in his program and requested reason for it. Your are giving an alternative solution.